# how to call woocommerce product description in a post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to display product description in a post. I have tried with this shortcode in my post:

```
[product_decrption id="1022"]
```

But nothing is showning in my post.Can you please help me. Is There any function needed to work with this?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, I don't think there is in-built shortcode for that.

But you can definitely make your own one like this:

```
function rohils_product_description_function( $atts, $content=null ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts( array('id' => ''), $atts));
    $product_data = new WC_Product($id);
    $content = $product_data->post->post_content;
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'product_decrption', 'rohils_product_description_function' );
```

And use is like : `[product_decrption id="8"]`

Comment: Yes in your theme's `functions.php` file. It should work. Is it giving you any error ? Make sure to put your product id in `[product_decrption id="ypur_product_id"]`.

Comment: ya i have included my correct product id..but nothing is showing.

Comment: Is it giving you any error ? I just tested above code in my local and it worked.